# VBA - как создать папки и переместить туда файлы?

Tags: excel, vba

Есть Excel файл, который содержит список файлов (100 штук) с их именами. Необходимо разбить все эти файлы по папкам не более 10 файлов в папке. То есть макрос сам должен создавать новую папку после заполнения предыдущей (Количество 10 штук). Эти папки должны находиться на 1 уровне.

Comment: а с чём возникли затруднения?

Comment: По какому принципу разбить? Методом случайной выборки?

Comment: Суть в чем, я не очень силен в VBA, данный эксель файл один из многих и некоторые из них имеют в себе до 930000 строк. В ручную несколько файлов сделать не проблема, но на будущее сделать цикл было бы классно. Разбивка по порядку. Первые 10 строк с именами файлов должны соответствовать 10 файлам в созданной папке. Следующие 10 следующим десяти

Comment: SO - это не место, где вы можете попросить бесплатно сделать за вас вашу работу. SO - это место, где вы можете задать вопрос и попросить помощи в решении задачи, но не решить ее за вас. Покажите, что вы уже сделали, какие у вас проблемы, что именно не получается

Comment: @lDrakonl Суть в том, что разбивку по 10 строкам я сделать могу, но не имею ни малейшего понятия как через VBA можно создавать папку и осуществлять перенос данных файлов.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/creating-deleting-and-moving-files-and-directories

Comment: @lDrakonl, спасибо статья полезная, однако это все как-то нужно попытаться сделать из под оболочки VBA. Данная же статья описывает действия только в VB оболочке

Comment: Файл содержит список, а где сами файлы? В комментариях Вы пишете о почти миллионе строк... Как Ваш первый вопрос (о разбивке поблочно) связан с этим? Что Вы подразумеваете под уровнем папок ("должны находиться на первом уровне?"). При чем здесь метка bat?. Очень туманно объясняете. И таки да -  у Вас только ТЗ, без попыток решения.

Comment: @lDrakonl судя по появившемуся ответу - то место :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обидевшись на ваши ответы, и посидев немного с VBA все таки написал скрипт, хоть и вышел за пределы сроков. Надеюсь вам пригодится, так что я выложу его сюда

```
Sub Кнопка1_Щелчок()
Dim i As Long
Dim ActWB As Workbook
Dim avInp(), fl As Object
Dim Kol_pid, Pid, kol1 As Integer
Dim Stolbec, StrokaOtsch As Integer
Dim NameFile() As String
Dim NewFoldPth, OldFoldPth, FoldPth, NewFolder1, NewFolder As String
Dim ki, counter As Long
Dim Fiyli() As String
Dim Stolbec1 As String
Dim iSheet As Integer ' Индекс листа
Dim sFPName As String ' Имя последней папки перед нумерацией


Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Stolbec1 = Application.InputBox("Укажите номер столбца, в котором находятся наименования файлов", "Номер столбца", "3")
Kol_pid = Application.InputBox("Укажите количество файлов в папке",
 "Номер папки", "3")
StrokaOtsch = Application.InputBox("Укажите номер строки начала данных", "Номер строки", "3")
StolbecOut = Application.InputBox("Укажите номер столбца куда писать пути", _ "Номер столбца", "3")


Stolbec = CInt(Stolbec1)
StrokaOtsch = CInt(StrokaOtsch)
StolbecOut = CInt(StolbecOut)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
i1_n = Cells(Rows.Count, Stolbec).End(xlUp).Row
Set ActWB = ActiveWorkbook
iSheet = ActiveSheet.Index

' NewFolder = Application.InputBox("Укажите имя папки, в которую необходимо перенести файлы", "Имя новой папки", _
' "Файлы из списка")

' StrokaOtsch = Application.InputBox("Укажите номер строки, в которой находится шапка таблицы", _
' "Номер строки", "1")
' NewFolder = "fileout"
' counter = 3

' StrokaOtsch = "1"
Pid = 1


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Папка Откуда копировать файлы"
    .ButtonName = "Select": .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show Then FoldPth = .SelectedItems(1) Else Exit Sub
End With

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Папка Куда копировать файлы"
    .ButtonName = "Select": .AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .Show Then NewFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1) Else Exit Sub
    'MsgBox (.SelectedItems(1))
End With

'NewFolderPath = NewFolderPath & "\"



Time_1 = Timer
If Right(NewFolder, 1) <> "\" Then NewFolder = NewFolder & "\"
If Right(FoldPth, 1) <> "\" Then FoldPth = FoldPth & "\"

bbb = Split(NewFolderPath, "\")

sFPName = bbb(UBound(bbb))


ReDim NameFile(i1_n - StrokaOtsch)

'For i1 = 1 To i1_n - StrokaOtsch + 1
'    If Cells(StrokaOtsch + i1 - 1, Stolbec) <> "" Then
'    n = n + 1
'    NameFile(n) = Cells(StrokaOtsch + i1 - 1, Stolbec)
'    End If
' Next i1

ReDim Preserve NameFile(n)
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
With FSO

        If Not .FolderExists(NewFolderPath & "\" & Pid & "\") Then .CreateFolder NewFolderPath & "\" & Pid & "\"
        'создание нового каталога куда копировать каталога
    With .GetFolder(FoldPth)
        ' If .Files.Count = 0 Then MsgBox "Файлов в указанном пути не найдено", 48: Exit Sub
        'проверка наличия файлов откуда происходит копирование


      '  ReDim Fiyly(.Files.Count)
      '      For Each fl In .Files
      '          ki = ki + 1
      '          Fiyly(ki) = fl.Name
                ' MsgBox (Fiyly(ki))  Заполнение массива именами файлов, находящихся в каталоге которые надо копировать
      '      Next fl
                kol1 = 1
            For i1 = StrokaOtsch To i1_n
       '     For i = 1 To UBound(Fiyly)

            If Cells(i1, Stolbec) <> "" Then

                ' MsgBox (Cells(i1, Stolbec))
                  '  NameFile(i1) = Cells(i1, Stolbec)
        '        If Fiyly(i) = NameFile(i1) Then
                    If kol1 = Kol_pid + 1 Then
                        Pid = Pid + 1
                        With FSO
                            If Not .FolderExists(NewFolderPath & "\" & Pid & "\") Then .CreateFolder NewFolderPath & "\" & Pid & "\"
                        End With
                        kol1 = 1
                    End If
                ' MsgBox (FoldPth & NameFile(i1) & "Новая куда" & NewFolderPath)
                If FSO.FileExists(FoldPth & Cells(i1, Stolbec)) Then
                     Kol = Kol + 1
                     kol1 = kol1 + 1


                    FSO.MoveFile FoldPth & Cells(i1, Stolbec), NewFolderPath & "\" & Pid & "\"
                    ActWB.Sheets(iSheet).Cells(i1, StolbecOut).Value = sFPName & "\" & Pid & "\" & Cells(i1, Stolbec)
                End If
         '       End If

          '  Next i
             End If
            Next i1
    End With
End With
time_ = Time_1 - Timer
Time_delta = Format(time_ / 24 / 60 / 60, "hh\ч mm\м ss\с")
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox ("Выполнено за " & Time_delta & Chr(13) & "Количество перемещённых файлов :" & Kol)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Начальные условия, от которых отталкивался:

1. В списке указаны полные пути к файлам
2. Список находится в одном столбце

Если указаны только имена файлов без пути и сами файлы раскиданы по всем дискам, то нужно уточнять условия.

```
Sub MovingFiles()
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim R As Long
    Dim C As Long
    Dim FSO
    Dim StoreFolder As String
    Dim FolderCounter As Long
    Dim FileCounter As Integer
    Dim DestinationFolder As String

    Set WB = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    ' Имя листа со списком файлов
    Set WS = WB.Worksheets("ListOfFiles")

    ' Создаем объект для работы с папками и файлами
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Место, где будут создаваться папки с файлами
    StoreFolder = "C:\Users\admin\Documents\move_test\Store\"

    ' Проверяем и создаем, если не существует, данную папку
    If Not FSO.FolderExists(StoreFolder) Then
        FSO.CreateFolder (StoreFolder)
    End If

    ' Номер строки, с которой начинается список файлов
    R = 1
    ' Номер столбца, в котором находится список файлов
    C = 1

    ' Счетчик создаваемых папок
    FolderCounter = 0
    ' Счетчик перемещенных файлов
    FileCounter = 0
    ' Путь к папке для переноса файлов
    DestinationFolder = StoreFolder & Format(FolderCounter, "0000") & "\"
    ' Если ее не существует, то создаем
    If Not FSO.FolderExists(DestinationFolder) Then
        FSO.CreateFolder (DestinationFolder)
    End If
    ' Читаем список файлов, пока не встретим пустую строку
    While Not IsEmpty(WS.Cells(R, C))
        If FSO.FileExists(WS.Cells(R, C).Value) Then
            FSO.MoveFile WS.Cells(R, C).Value, DestinationFolder & FSO.GetFileName(WS.Cells(R, C).Value)
            FileCounter = FileCounter + 1
        End If
        If FileCounter = 10 Then
            FileCounter = 0
            FolderCounter = FolderCounter + 1
            DestinationFolder = StoreFolder & Format(FolderCounter, "0000") & "\"
            If Not FSO.FolderExists(DestinationFolder) Then
                FSO.CreateFolder (DestinationFolder)
            End If
        End If
        R = R + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

[Полезная ссылка](https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/folders-file-handling/)